# Share data flow in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We use same data flow logic of SSIS sync tables between different source SQL servers with different instances and target servers with different instances, same databases schema and database name.

For example, sync ServerB/DB1 to ServerA/DB1, ServerB/DB2 to ServerA/DB2, ServerC/DB3 to ServerA/DB3.

Currently we have to create SSIS packages between source DB and target DB one by one. Any idea how to share the same data flow for all databases data synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop Container to loop through different instances. You may pass dynamic parameter or create a table and fetch parameters.

Comment: thank you, i save source and target database connection string in db table, and loop them by loop Container, that is work well.